# Unable to run openoffice in headless mode

Tags: linux, openoffice, x-server, headless, xvfb

I want to automoate some PPT -> PDF conversions, so I want to run openoffice in headless mode for scripting.

On my machine with X running I can start opemoffice in headless mode via

`soffice -accept="socket,port=8100;urp;" -headless`

This doesn't seem to work on a server with X not running.

```
$ soffice -accept="socket,port=8100;urp;" -headless
/usr/lib/openoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display: 
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
  or check permissions of your X-Server
  (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
$
```

The error doesnt seem to make sense as well, as the point of specifying `-headless` was so that I do not need X, while this command seems to look for X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/).

Comment: That still requires a OpenOffice running in headless mode, which I am unable to do.

Comment: Well yes but unoconv takes care of it.. Or do you mean you tried it out and got the same error?

Answer (score 1):

First type:

```
xhost +
```

Then type:

```
echo DISPLAY
setenv DISPLAY <hostname of your machine>:0.0
```

Then execute OpenOffice in headless mode.

Comment: Just a note: you might want to execute `echo $DISPLAY` with the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

If OOo hasn't been run on that server before you'll need to bypass the registration wizard.  Looks like the option to do that is `-nofirststartwizard`; however there may be other complications as mentioned [here](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=18837).