# How to fix X11 error: Can't open display

Tags: linux, xorg, openoffice, libreoffice

I installed libreoffice.x86_64 using yum from the CentOS repository on my CentOS basic server.  When running the following command from the shell, I get the following X11 error. xhost is installed on my box but X does not appear to be.  What causes this error and how do I fix it?

```
[root@desktop ~]# HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_12.xlsx
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display:
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
[root@desktop ~]#
```

**EDIT**

Per comments, I did the following, and the error went away and the document was converted.

```
[root@desktop ~]# yum install tigervnc-server
[root@desktop ~]# vncserver :0
[root@desktop ~]# HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice -display :0 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
```

My end goal is to use PHP through Apache to run this command.  When attempting to do so, it isn't converted and I receive no error or feedback. I then tried to do the same command using a different user, but am having similar problems.  Any suggestions?

```
-sh-4.1$ HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice -display :0 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display: :0
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
-sh-4.1$
```

**EDIT2**

If I reboot server and do `vncserver :0` under the other user, then try to convert the document, it just hangs indefinitely.

**EDIT3**

Tried the wizard both with and without setting display, but no good.  Maybe some sort of permission problem?

```
[NotionCommotion@laptop root]$ HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice -display :0  --nofirststartwizard --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice: line 68: cd: /root: Permission denied
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display: :0
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
[NotionCommotion@laptop root]$ HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice  --nofirststartwizard --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_34.doc
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice: line 68: cd: /root: Permission denied
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display:
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
[NotionCommotion@laptop root]$
```

Comment: Maybe the runtime switch `-display :0`?

Comment: libreoffice is clearly trying to contact your X server (which you seemed to indicate you don't have running) I assume that is why you were trying `--headless`. Either that wasn't the right flag or it doesn't work the way you expect (and still requires an X server to function).

Comment: @EtanReisner  I've successfully used this on other servers, however, those other servers probably had gnome installed which might have installed X server.  How do I tell if X server is installed and/or running?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Like this?
`[root@desktop root]# HOME=/tmp/ayb; /usr/bin/libreoffice -display :0 --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir /tmp/ayb /tmp/ayb/document_12.xlsx
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display: :0
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)`

Comment: The idea of headless is that it eliminates the need for X - it isn't clear that this functionality is complete.  Instead of installing all of X, I would install vncserver and run it as `vncserver :0`.  Then export DISPLAY=:0

Comment: An X server installed is not enough. That error means that libreoffice has attempted to actually connect to an X server. That means one needs to be running. To check that look at the list of running processes. And yes, installing a more minimal X server is certainly an option if all you need is something to respond when libreoffice tries to connect (you might even be able to fake it up with a simple script if you wanted to try).

Comment: @Paul.  I installed tigervnc-server, and added -display :0 to my original libreoffice command, and it appears to work.  Vncserver requires a password which is causing problems when I run this command using PHP's exec(), but that is a different issue.

Comment: @EtanReisner.  I do not appear to have an X server running.  What would it show up as?

Comment: startx, xinit, X, xorg  or something else along those lines.

Comment: @EtanReisner.  Maybe I do have it after starting vncserver?  X shows up but not startx, xinit, or xorg. `root     19207  0.0  0.0  86244 10040 ?        S    01:43   0:00 /usr/bin/Xvnc :0 -desktop desktop.badobe.com:0 (root) -auth /root/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -pn
root     19213  0.0  0.0  47776  1988 ?        S    01:43   0:00 vncconfig -iconic`

Comment: Please looked at my amended original post for additional information.

Comment: The `No protocol specified` error sounds like the issue that the `man xhost` instruction is supposed to fix (your user doesn't have access to the X server it is trying to use). The hang issue is something else, perhaps the wizard issue mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/124022/107862)?

Comment: @EtanReisner.  The wizard didn't seem to help. See Edit 3 revisions to original post.  Maybe a permission issue?

Comment: What user ran the X server? You need to run libreoffice as that user or give that user access to the X server. I'm not sure what the cd issue is but I assume that's unrelated and not a problem you will have in your live/php scenario.

Comment: @EtanReisner.  X server was installed and started by root.  Root can use libreoffice to convert files.  When NotionCommotion is logged on, I get the errors.  I added NotionCommotion by editing /etc/sysconfig/vncservers and adding `VNCSERVERS="0:NotionCommotion"
VNCSERVERARGS[0]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -localhost"`.  I also added NotionCommotion's normal password using `vncpasswd` (don't know if this was correct?)

Comment: I don't know anything about configuring tigervnc so I can't comment if that is the correct configuration but you should probably just start the server as the user who wants to use it to avoid these sorts of problems (also you almost certainly shouldn't be running X as root). And as I've said, and as the error says, to control access to a running X server (at the X level, the vnc level is different) you want to look at xhost/xauth and friends. You might be better off not using vnc for this at all if that just complicates things too much.

Comment: @EtanReisner.  I've since uninstalled tigervnc (just VNC I think per http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server). How do I know if the x server is running and under which user (I am sure it is root, but how do I check?)?  When running xauth as NotionCommotion, I get a permission error: `-sh-4.1$ xauth
xauth:  /tmp/ayb/.Xauthority not writable, changes will be ignored`.  Maybe part of the problem?

Comment: ps will tell you which user is running the process. That error is *a* problem but that is probably just because root created that file. Change the ownership and that should go away. That might be enough to let your xhost/xauth command do what you want though. I'd still recommend killing the X that root ran and starting a new X session as your desired user.

Comment: I have two servers: desktop and laptop.  It appears that X (that is Xorg, right?) is only running on the laptop.  `[root@laptop ~]# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
28717 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
28759 pts/0    00:00:00 su
29399 pts/0    00:00:00 su
29407 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
29563 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[root@laptop ~]# ps -e | grep X
 2654 tty1     00:03:04 Xorg
[root@laptop ~]#`  desktop doesn't display any X.  To be continued with maybe a clue!

Comment: Ah ha, just tried to kill the process on the laptop (the only one I have a GUI) when I was SSH'd, and my laptop GUI screen reset!  I then logged onto the laptop directly (not with ssh) as NotionCommotion and was able to convert a file.  So, it appears I do not have X running when I am ssh'd in?  Don't know if this is a clue, but hope so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are going headless, then you shouldn't need X.  See [Convert file to PDF using LibreOffice under user apache (i.e. when using PHP)](https://superuser.com/questions/627266/convert-file-to-pdf-using-libreoffice-under-user-apache-i-e-when-using-php) for a working solution.

Comment: I got the same issue. The issue is easily reproducible: It works in the command line, but it doesn't work if I issue an "unset DISPLAY" before. So for some reason LibreOffice 5.1 does need a working X, even when running --headless. My command line: "exec /usr/bin/ooffice --headless --convert-to pptx /tmp/filecCn4GT.odp". Frank

Answer (score 9):

This is an old one, but I ran into it myself today.  the trick to using "--headless" is that you need to have libreoffice-headless installed (ie: `yum install libreoffice-headless`).  not all libreoffice installs have libreoffice-headless installed - for example, mine today.

Found this nugget buried in the link user1032531 posted.

It would be nice if using --headless without the appropriate package generated an error to that effect, but it doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21514

```
yum install openoffice.org-headless
```

Comment: Could you include some more information? Consider marking the yum line as code using four spaces or a tab to indent it.